# An invalid argument in TFL with a contradiction as conclusion

Tags: logic

I think this is possible.
I know all arguments in tfl with tautologies as conclusions are valid. I know a valid argument cant have a contradiction as a conclusion. But this is throwing me a bit. If it always evaluates to false, then it is inavlid automatically right?

Comment: In classical logic, from a contradiction anything follows, including other contradictions. So you can have a valid argument with a contradiction as a conclusion, provided the premises of the argument are inconsistent.

Comment: It is valid because there is no case where the premises are true and the conclusion is false.